# SQL Developer - How do I get MAX & AVG to draw from one column and filter from themselves?

Tags: sql, max, average

I need to find out the AVG and MAX of a column, display the results in two columns, and then filter every row by whether the AVG and MAX have a difference of twenty or more.

My code currently does most of this, the only thing I need to figure out is the final filtering.

This is my code:

```
SELECT b.BOWLERFIRSTNAME || ' ' || b.BOWLERLASTNAME "Bowler 
   Name", TO_CHAR(AVG(bs.RAWSCORE), '999') "Current Average", 
   MAX(bs.RAWSCORE)"High Score"
FROM BOWLERS b
   JOIN BOWLER_SCORES bs USING (BOWLERID)
WHERE bs.RAWSCORE = (SELECT MAX(bs.RAWSCORE)
                       FROM BOWLER_SCORES
                       GROUP BY bs.RAWSCORE)
GROUP BY b.BOWLERFIRSTNAME, b.BOWLERLASTNAME
ORDER BY b.BOWLERFIRSTNAME ASC;
```

This is what I am getting as an output:

[image: The Above Code Output]

My code generates the correct amount in each column for each player, but I can't figure out how to filter the query to exclude any player who's "Highest Score" isn't more than 20 points above their average.

Here is my goal:

[image: Table goal through query]

I am very new to SQL so any additional pointers or advice you may have would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Having clause between group by and order by :

```
group by <statements>
having max(variable)-avg(variable)>20
order by <statements>
```